# DBFlow make simple OneToMany relation ship

Tags: android

I'm trying to make simple relationShiop between two table as `Sahmiye`and `FoodData` with `OneToMany`, in first time i get this error:

`Error:(69, 42) error: cannot find symbol variable queenForeignKeyContainer_id`

My `Sahmiye` class:

```
@Table(database = AppDatabase.class)
public class Sahmiye {
    @PrimaryKey(autoincrement = true)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @Column
    private String parentId;

    public List<FoodData> foodData;

    public Sahmiye() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(String parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public List<FoodData> getFoodData() {
        return foodData;
    }

    public void setFoodData(List<FoodData> foodData) {
        this.foodData = foodData;
    }

    @OneToMany(methods = {OneToMany.Method.ALL}, variableName = "foodData")
    public List<FoodData> getMyFoodDatas() {
        if (foodData == null || foodData.isEmpty()) {
            foodData = SQLite.select()
                    .from(FoodData.class)
                    .where(FoodData_Table.queenForeignKeyContainer_id.eq(id))
                    .queryList();
        }
        return foodData;
    }
}
```

and my `FoodData` Table:

```
@Table(database = AppDatabase.class)
public class FoodData {
    @PrimaryKey(autoincrement = true)
    private int     id;

    @Column
    private String  title;

    @Column
    private boolean rice;

    @Column
    private int     foodId;

    @Column
    private int     parentId;

    public FoodData() {
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public boolean isRice() {
        return rice;
    }

    public void setRice(boolean rice) {
        this.rice = rice;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getFoodId() {
        return foodId;
    }
    public void setFoodId(int foodId) {
        this.foodId = foodId;
    }
    public int getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }
    public void setParentId(int parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }
}
```

could you fix my relation ship? thanks in advance